# Write to file from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to write an ArrayList to a file in java. This is what I do in **main class**:

To write Strings into the ArrayList I do:

```
list.add(String);
```

Then, to write it to the file:

```
readWrite.writing(list);
```

list is: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`

`readWrite` references to this class where I have defined the methods to read/write to a file:

```
 public void writing(ArrayList listToWrite) throws IOException {
    fileOutPutStream = new FileOutputStream (file);
    write = new ObjectOutputStream (fileOutPutStream);
    for (int i=0; i<=listToWrite.size(); i++){
        write.writeObject(listToWrite.get(i));
    }
    write.close();
}
```

When trying it on the console, I'm getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at //*I GET REFERENCED TO THIS LINE IN THE CODE ABOVE:* **write.writeObject(listToWrite.get(i));**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful with your limits: with `<=` you go one item past the end of the list.

```
for (int i=0; i<listToWrite.size(); i++){
```

Then again, note that `ArrayList` is itself serializable. You could just write it to the file without looping:

```
write = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutPutStream);
write.writeObject(listToWrite);
write.close();
```

Comment: Works perfect! I'll try the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Might be best to just go with:

```
for (String str : listToWrite){
    // DO WORK HERE
}
```

That way you don't have to worry about all of that messy indexing business.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would also be:

```
BufferedWriter outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
outputWriter.write(Arrays.toString(array));
```